# Talend - tWebServiceInput and operator overload

Tags: web-services, liferay, talend

I´m calling a webservice with 2 methods with same name (Liferay - adduser), and I have this error:

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:Duplicate operation with name=addUser,
 found in binding '{urn:http.service.portal.liferay.com}Portal_UserServiceSoapBinding'
```

This is the part of WSDL.

```
<wsdl:operation name="addUser" parameterOrder="companyId autoPassword password1 password2 autoScreenName screenName emailAddress facebookId openId locale firstName middleName lastName prefixId suffixId male birthdayMonth birthdayDay birthdayYear jobTitle groupIds organizationIds roleIds userGroupIds addresses emailAddresses phones websites announcementsDelivers sendEmail serviceContext">
        <wsdl:input message="impl:addUserRequest" name="addUserRequest"/>
        <wsdl:output message="impl:addUserResponse" name="addUserResponse"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="addUser" parameterOrder="companyId autoPassword password1 password2 autoScreenName screenName emailAddress facebookId openId locale firstName middleName lastName prefixId suffixId male birthdayMonth birthdayDay birthdayYear jobTitle groupIds organizationIds roleIds userGroupIds sendEmail serviceContext">
        <wsdl:input message="impl:addUserRequest1" name="addUserRequest1"/>
        <wsdl:output message="impl:addUserResponse1" name="addUserResponse1"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
```

.
Any web service component in Talend work with a wsdl with overload? Is there a workaround?

Full stack

```
Exception in component tWebServiceInput_1
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Duplicate operation with name=addUser, found in binding '{urn:http.service.portal.liferay.com}Portal_UserServiceSoapBinding'.
    at com.ibm.wsdl.BindingImpl.getBindingOperation(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.setOperation(Call.java:1373)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.setOperation(Call.java:1652)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Service.createCall(Service.java:546)
    at org.talend.DynamicInvoker.invokeMethod(DynamicInvoker.java:244)
    at org.talend.DynamicInvoker.main(DynamicInvoker.java:190)
    at org.talend.DynamicInvoker.main(DynamicInvoker.java:131)
    at portal_migration.getfrompc_0_1.GetFromPC.tWebServiceInput_1Process(GetFromPC.java:4122)
    at portal_migration.getfrompc_0_1.GetFromPC.tLDAPInput_1Process(GetFromPC.java:3988)
    at portal_migration.getfrompc_0_1.GetFromPC.runJobInTOS(GetFromPC.java:6367)
    at portal_migration.getfrompc_0_1.GetFromPC.main(GetFromPC.java:6208)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:Duplicate operation with name=addUser, found in binding '{urn:http.service.portal.liferay.com}Portal_UserServiceSoapBinding'. Date: 12-09-2014 14:47:40
```

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace that accompanies the error?

Comment: I'm feeling a bit bleary eyed at the minute so can't quite follow the source for the [wsdl4j library](http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/com/ibm/wsdl/BindingImpl.html) but it says you should be able to overload stuff. I can't quite work out how the IllegalArgumentException is being thrown because it looks like found should always be false at that point.

Comment: Is a Talend problem, but i must workaround, and i dont know ....